# oracle subtract 2 dates then divide by count

Tags: sql, oracle, average, date-difference

I am trying to do  (date1 - date2)/ count(date1)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(submit_date, 'iw'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') TIMESTAMP
     , ( TO_CHAR( (closed_date - submit_date),'dd/mm/yyyy') )
                                             / count(closed_date)  AVG  
  FROM t_oi_request_form rf
  LEFT JOIN t_oi_requester_domain rd
    ON rf.REQUEST_TYPE = rd.requester_domain_id
  LEFT JOIN t_oi_report_type rt
    ON rf.requestor_domain = rt.REPORT_TYPE_ID
 WHERE submit_date
          between TO_DATE('2015-11-02  00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
              AND TO_DATE('2016-02-08 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
 GROUP BY TRUNC(submit_date, 'iw'),
          ( TO_CHAR( (closed_date - submit_date),'dd/mm/yyyy') )
                                                / count(closed_date)
 ORDER BY TRUNC(submit_date, 'iw')
```

I get error `Error in query: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Here is sample data

```
SUBMIT_DATE | CLOSED_DATE
---------------------------
  02-NOV-15 |   12-NOV-15
  02-NOV-15 |   03-NOV-15
  04-NOV-15 |   20-JAN-16
  04-NOV-15 |   11-NOV-15
  04-NOV-15 |   19-JAN-16
  05-NOV-15 |   31-DEC-15
  05-NOV-15 |   05-NOV-15
  06-NOV-15 |   06-NOV-15
  05-NOV-15 |   05-NOV-15
  04-NOV-15 |   05-NOV-15
  06-NOV-15 |     NULL
  10-NOV-15 |   11-NOV-15
  13-NOV-15 |   17-NOV-15
  13-NOV-15 |   17-NOV-15
  09-NOV-15 |   11-NOV-15
  11-NOV-15 |   17-NOV-15
  11-NOV-15 |   11-NOV-15
  13-NOV-15 |   17-NOV-15
  11-NOV-15 |   11-NOV-15
  10-NOV-15 |   13-NOV-15
  11-NOV-15 |   11-NOV-15
  19-NOV-15 |   19-NOV-15
  17-NOV-15 |   20-JAN-16
  17-NOV-15 |   18-DEC-15
  19-NOV-15 |   03-DEC-15
  17-NOV-15 |     NULL
  19-NOV-15 |   15-DEC-15
  16-NOV-15 |     NULL
  18-NOV-15 |   19-NOV-15
  20-NOV-15 |   20-NOV-15
  19-NOV-15 |   20-NOV-15
  20-NOV-15 |   25-NOV-15
  20-NOV-15 |   25-NOV-15
  17-NOV-15 |   17-NOV-15
  19-NOV-15 |   20-NOV-15
  19-NOV-15 |   20-NOV-15
  19-NOV-15 |   20-NOV-15
  17-NOV-15 |   17-NOV-15
  17-NOV-15 |   17-NOV-15
  17-NOV-15 |   17-NOV-15
  17-NOV-15 |   17-NOV-15
  17-NOV-15 |   17-NOV-15
  18-NOV-15 |   20-NOV-15
  19-NOV-15 |   20-NOV-15
  19-NOV-15 |   20-NOV-15
  20-NOV-15 |   20-NOV-15
  20-NOV-15 |   20-NOV-15
  26-NOV-15 |   02-DEC-15
  25-NOV-15 |   26-NOV-15
  27-NOV-15 |   01-DEC-15
  25-NOV-15 |   25-NOV-15
  24-NOV-15 |   25-NOV-15
  25-NOV-15 |   01-DEC-15
  26-NOV-15 |   18-JAN-16
  25-NOV-15 |   30-NOV-15
  26-NOV-15 |   06-JAN-16
  26-NOV-15 |   27-NOV-15
  25-NOV-15 |   31-DEC-15
  26-NOV-15 |     NULL
  25-NOV-15 |   31-DEC-15
  25-NOV-15 |   31-DEC-15
  24-NOV-15 |     NULL
  26-NOV-15 |   11-DEC-15
  30-NOV-15 |   01-DEC-15
  03-DEC-15 |   15-DEC-15
  30-NOV-15 |   01-DEC-15
  02-DEC-15 |   04-DEC-15
  03-DEC-15 |   04-DEC-15
  02-DEC-15 |   04-DEC-15
  02-DEC-15 |     NULL
  04-DEC-15 |   04-DEC-15
  03-DEC-15 |   03-DEC-15
  02-DEC-15 |   04-DEC-15
  10-DEC-15 |   16-DEC-15
  09-DEC-15 |   16-DEC-15
  11-DEC-15 |     NULL
  08-DEC-15 |     NULL
  09-DEC-15 |   09-DEC-15
  09-DEC-15 |   09-DEC-15
  09-DEC-15 |     NULL
  10-DEC-15 |     NULL
  15-DEC-15 |   16-DEC-15
  17-DEC-15 |   18-DEC-15
  16-DEC-15 |   29-DEC-15
  15-DEC-15 |   16-DEC-15
  14-DEC-15 |   16-DEC-15
  23-DEC-15 |   06-JAN-16
  24-DEC-15 |   07-JAN-16
  22-DEC-15 |     NULL
  31-DEC-15 |     NULL
  08-JAN-16 |   26-JAN-16
  07-JAN-16 |   11-JAN-16
  07-JAN-16 |   11-JAN-16
  04-JAN-16 |   06-JAN-16
  05-JAN-16 |   06-JAN-16
  04-JAN-16 |   06-JAN-16
  04-JAN-16 |   06-JAN-16
  07-JAN-16 |   11-JAN-16
  06-JAN-16 |   06-JAN-16
  12-JAN-16 |   13-JAN-16
  13-JAN-16 |   20-JAN-16
  11-JAN-16 |   11-JAN-16
  12-JAN-16 |   13-JAN-16
  22-JAN-16 |     NULL
  18-JAN-16 |     NULL
  21-JAN-16 |   22-JAN-16
  19-JAN-16 |   20-JAN-16
  21-JAN-16 |   22-JAN-16
  21-JAN-16 |   22-JAN-16
  19-JAN-16 |     NULL
  22-JAN-16 |     NULL
  19-JAN-16 |     NULL
  20-JAN-16 |   22-JAN-16
  19-JAN-16 |   21-JAN-16
  21-JAN-16 |   22-JAN-16
  21-JAN-16 |   21-JAN-16
  20-JAN-16 |     NULL
  18-JAN-16 |     NULL
  18-JAN-16 |     NULL
  18-JAN-16 |     NULL
  26-JAN-16 |     NULL
  26-JAN-16 |     NULL
  26-JAN-16 |     NULL
  26-JAN-16 |     NULL
  26-JAN-16 |     NULL
  29-JAN-16 |   05-FEB-16
  26-JAN-16 |   05-FEB-16
  29-JAN-16 |     NULL
  29-JAN-16 |     NULL
  26-JAN-16 |   26-JAN-16
  26-JAN-16 |     NULL
  26-JAN-16 |   26-JAN-16
  04-FEB-16 |     NULL
  05-FEB-16 |     NULL
  02-FEB-16 |   05-FEB-16
  04-FEB-16 |     NULL
  01-FEB-16 |     NULL
  02-FEB-16 |   02-FEB-16
  05-FEB-16 |     NULL
  01-FEB-16 |     NULL
  03-FEB-16 |     NULL
  03-FEB-16 |     NULL
```

I am trying to calculate **Average Open to Close Time (days)**, I may be doing it wrong

Comment: Which table does the submit_date column belong to?

Comment: they all belong to `t_oi_request_form`

Comment: I'd wrap most of it into a derived table, incl the to_char stuff. And do the final GROUP BY at lop level.

Comment: You do have unbalanced parentheses, but I'd remove the redundant ones; that just leads to ORA-00934 because of the `count` in the group-by clause, which isn't allowed. And more importantly `closed_date - submit_date` will give you a number, which isn't going to work in your `to_char`. You need to rethink this. Unfortunately it isn't clear what you're really trying to achieve - maybe with sample data and results and an explanation someone can help you more. (TIMESTAMP and AVG are also reserved words so not a good choice for your column aliases).

Comment: @AlexPoole I have added sample data

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the average time difference between `submit_date` and `closed_date` for each week:

```
SELECT TRUNC(submit_date, 'iw')
   ,AVG(closed_date - submit_date)
   --,AVG(TRUNC(closed_date) - TRUNC(submit_date)) -- ??

FROM t_oi_request_form rf
LEFT JOIN t_oi_requester_domain rd
  ON rf.REQUEST_TYPE = rd.requester_domain_id
LEFT JOIN t_oi_report_type rt
  ON rf.requestor_domain = rt.REPORT_TYPE_ID
WHERE submit_date between TO_DATE('2015-11-02 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
                      AND TO_DATE('2016-02-08 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY TRUNC(submit_date, 'iw')
ORDER BY TRUNC(submit_date, 'iw')
```

There's no need to do a SUM/COUNT because aggregate functions ignore NULLs anyway. And if you don't care about NULLs you might be able to change the outer joins to inner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an oracle guy but just eye balling your code I can see missing parentheses:

You have:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(submit_date, 'iw'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') TIMESTAMP
,( TO_char( (closed_date - submit_date),'dd/mm/yyyy') ) / count(closed_date)  AVG


FROM t_oi_request_form rf
LEFT JOIN t_oi_requester_domain rd ON rf.REQUEST_TYPE = rd.requester_domain_id
LEFT JOIN t_oi_report_type rt ON rf.requestor_domain = rt.REPORT_TYPE_ID
WHERE submit_date between TO_DATE('2015-11-02  00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
    AND TO_DATE('2016-02-08 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY TRUNC(submit_date, 'iw'),( TO_char( (closed_date - submit_date),'dd/mm/yyyy') ) / count(closed_date) )
ORDER BY TRUNC(submit_date, 'iw')
```

But you are missing a parentheses in the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(submit_date, 'iw'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') [TIMESTAMP]
,( TO_char( (closed_date - submit_date),'dd/mm/yyyy') ) / count(closed_date) [AVG]


FROM t_oi_request_form rf
LEFT JOIN t_oi_requester_domain rd ON rf.REQUEST_TYPE = rd.requester_domain_id
LEFT JOIN t_oi_report_type rt ON rf.requestor_domain = rt.REPORT_TYPE_ID
WHERE submit_date between TO_DATE('2015-11-02  00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
    AND TO_DATE('2016-02-08 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY TRUNC(submit_date, 'iw'),(( TO_char( (closed_date - submit_date),'dd/mm/yyyy') ) / count(closed_date) )
ORDER BY TRUNC(submit_date, 'iw')
```

this should resolve:

> Error in query: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 0):

The expressions in the SELECT list seems a little overly complicated, to calculate the number of days between two dates, and then aggregate those into an average.

I'm not understanding why you wouldn't just use the `AVG` aggregate function:

```
  AVG( rf.closed_date - rf.submit_date )
```

that is, something like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(rf.submit_date,'iw'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS TIMESTAMP
     , AVG( rf.closed_date - rf.submit_date )           AS avg_days_to_close
  FROM t_oi_request_form rf
  LEFT
  JOIN t_oi_requester_domain rd
    ON rf.REQUEST_TYPE = rd.requester_domain_id
  LEFT
  JOIN t_oi_report_type rt
    ON rf.requestor_domain = rt.REPORT_TYPE_ID
 WHERE rf.submit_date >= TO_DATE('2015-11-02','YYYY-MM-DD')
   AND rf.submit_date <  TO_DATE('2016-02-08','YYYY-MM-DD')
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(rf.submit_date,'iw'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
 ORDER BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(rf.submit_date,'iw'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

---

We could get an equivalent result using `SUM()`, `COUNT()` and a division operation:

```
 SUM( rf.closed_date - rf.submit_date)  / COUNT( rf.closed_date - rf.submit_date)
```